# character limit in a word inside a textarea dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, textarea

i am trying to put a limit on number of characters in a word. i am successful to find, if someone is entering more then 15 character.i am displaying a message right now. what i want to do is, if some one enter more then 15 characters ... the java script display a alert and then delete all letters leaving first 14 characters in that word. i tried to find some helpful functions but never found something useful. 
i want to check for the character limit dynamically when the user is still entering.
my code is half complete but it has one flaw. it is displaying the message when a count is reaching more then 15 it displays a alert. now user can still save that string that has more than 15 char in a word. hope i explained it all.thanks to all,for everyone that is gonna put some effort in advance.

```
<textarea id="txt" name="area" onclick="checkcharactercount()"></textarea>


function checkcharactercount(){
  document.body.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
      var val = document.getElementById("txt").value;
      var string = val.split(" ");
      for(i=0;i<string.length; i++) {
        len = string[i].length;
        if (len >= 15) {
          alert('you have exceeded the maximum number of charaters in a word!!!');
          break;
        }
      }
  });
}
```

Comment: Why not just use the html maxlength attribute? `<textarea maxlength="15"></textarea>`

Comment: Using a `maxlength` attribute or just `val.length` would be enough, wouldn't it ?

Comment: max length doesnt work, when we try to find word count.it just counts the caracter length of all string. means if i put a maxlength="50" . it is gonna include all spaces and everything. so in my case it is not gonna work. correct me if i am wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work like you want it to?

```js
var textArea = document.getElementById('txt');
textArea.addEventListener('keyup', function () {
  var val = textArea.value;
  var words = val.split(' ');
  for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    if (words[i].length > 14) {
      // the word is longer than 14 characters, use only the first 14
      words[i] = words[i].slice(0, 14);
    }
  }
  
  // join the words together again and put them into the text area
  textArea.value = words.join(' ');
});
```

```html
<textarea id="txt" name="area"></textarea>
```

Comment: thanks a lot . this is what i was looking for. looks like i have a long way to go in js :)